# HTML: empty <p></p> tag show no line break

Tags: html, css

We have a .NET application saving messages in axml. What we need to do is converting it to html. I have found a 3rd party lib "HtmlFromXamlConverter" does that, with a minor defect: If the axml contains multiple line breaks, it will be converted to something like:

```
<P ><SPAN STYLE="text-decoration:underline;" /> </P>
<P ><SPAN STYLE="text-decoration:underline;" /> </P>
<P ><SPAN STYLE="text-decoration:underline;" /> </P>
```

Which only appear as 1 line break. I cannot insert a " " as value because there is a underline style. So the question is, is there a way to config empty P tags `<p></p>` showing up as line breaks?

Comment: Does it need the underline style?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that with just CSS, you have to add a non-breakable space inside the paragraphs:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: I tried that. Too bad it will show up as a empty space with underline. :( I cannot remove the underline because in other cases it is useful.

Comment: Not good for example for links. It will show short underline.

Comment: You can replace the empty tag with a line break, ex. string.Replace("<b></b>", "<br />")

Answer (score 20):

How about adding a tiny inline block like so:

```
p:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  width:0px;
  outline:1px solid red; /* debug, remove me */
}
```

This will force even empty paragraphs to be of the line-height you've set.

Answer (score 18):

This solution gives empty paragraphs the current lineheight:

```
p:empty:before {
  content: ' ';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are clever solutions already mentioned, but one solution I like that uses *only CSS* is to set a minimum height on your `p` tags.

```
.myText {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.myText p {
  min-height: 18px;
}
```

This will make even empty `p` tags take up the same height as their neighbors, and you don't need to mess around with inserting text.

This is really good if you're displaying user input, because you might want to save that user input again and you'd need to carefully rip out all of the `&nbsp;`s or whatever else you inserted.

For downsides, It does require that you have some wrapping element. I also wish I could use relative line-heights but don't see a way to make that work.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML code is very odd and broken, but I presume you cannot fix it. The way to make an empty `p` produce an empty line using CSS, with the usual CSS caveats, is to set its height to the same as the line height and its margins to zero (removing the default top and bottom margins that would appear in this rendering otherwise):

```
p { height: 1.3em; margin: 0; }
```

This postulates a line height of 1.3, which is best set explicitly (instead of letting browsers default it):

```
* { line-height: 1.3; }
```

The value should be chosen according to the properties of the font; but 1.3 is reasonable for a typical situation.

If there are other `p` elements on the page, you need some added complexity to restrict the effect of the rule to the desired set only. (There is no way to select elements on the basis of its content in CSS; but JavaScript could be used for that.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the underlines and want to still add spaces you can override the inline styles with the !important tag in your CSS.

```
p span {
   text-decoration: none !important; 
   /* This will force the underline to go away if you want to add spaces */
}
```

If you just want to add some margin to the bottom of each paragraph tag you can do this:

```
p { 
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: <value>px;
}
```

Keep in mind this will affect all paragraphs on the page, applying a class to these would be the best solution for only tweaking these line breaking tags. You could then do something like:

```
.linebreak {
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: <value>px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use javascript to replace the empty < p > tags with < br >. Following solution uses jQuery:

```
var emptyPs = $('P > SPAN[STYLE="text-decoration:underline;"]').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $.trim($this.text()).length == 0;});

emptyPs.replaceWith('<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

everything is much simpler:

```css
  p:empty {
      display: none;
    }
```